# How to calculate the Electric field of an cylinder with length of infinity and given charge density of the surfac?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I know how to calculate the Electric field of this example if the given variable would be the charge density of the volume but since only the charge density of the area is given, I'm very confused because I'm wondering what my gaussian surface looks like. Normally it would be a volume which covers the cylinder but since I have just given the density of an area, I think my gaussian surface must be an area as well.

Comment: No, your gaussian surface has to cover the cylinder. You can take a cylinder encompassing your cylinder as gaussian surface. The surface charge density only states, that the charges are distributed on the surface. That is, if the density is rotational symmetric, there is no electric field in the inside.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That means the electric field outside the cylinder whil be $\frac{\sigma r^2}{2 \epsilon_0 R}$ instead of $\frac{\rho r^2}{2 \epsilon_0 R}$?

Comment: I think that means the surface is the same but I need to multiply my result with the unit vector in respect to the coordinate system I choose. So for example the result is $\frac{\sigma r^2}{2 \epsilon_0 R} \hat{e_y} $. Is this correct?

Comment: Almost. By symmetry the electric field goes only through the lateral surface. That is $\frac{2\pi R L\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}=2\pi r L E$.

Comment: The direction will be in radial direction $\hat{e}_r$.